# How can I manipulate the day value here without changing the hours?

Tags: r, data-mining

```
time<- as.POSIXct( db$times, format="%H:%M")
time <-  as.Date(time_booked)-1               #Change day to previous day
time <-as.POSIXct(time,format="%H:%M") #Times for yesterday
```

I need to change the day value to yesterday (i.e. day-1) only. The first line formats the times from the data frame (eg "2018-04-16 19:00:00 BST"). And the second line can change the day (i.e. 16 goes to 15) no problem but I lose the time. If I run the third line it defaults all the times to "01:00:00".

Is there a way to just change that day value without losing my times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deduct 86400 seconds (24hr*60min*60sec) from your date time object.

```
date <- as.POSIXct( "2018-04-16 19:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
date - 86400
[1] "2018-04-15 19:00:00 CEST"
```

or with lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
date - ddays()
[1] "2018-04-15 19:00:00 CEST"
```